# Why am I getting a "Not Implemented" error when unit testing firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am writing firebase storage security rules, and unit testing them with "@firebase/rules-unit-testing". When running the tests, I get the following error:

```
Not Implemented

      at node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/src/impl/rules.ts:64:11
      at step (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:74:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:55:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:45:58)
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
```

The only unit test I have currently is supposed to confirm that users cannot delete files.

Here is my code:

```js
import {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment,
  RulesTestEnvironment,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import {
  deleteObject,
  ref,
  uploadBytes,
} from "firebase/storage";
import * as fs from "fs";
const PROJECT_ID = "iurn-973d0";
let testEnv: RulesTestEnvironment;

describe("Firebase storage security rules", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
      projectId: PROJECT_ID,
      firestore: {
        rules: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../storage.rules", "utf-8"),
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 9199,
      },
    });
  });
  beforeEach(async () => {
    if(!testEnv) return
    testEnv.clearStorage();
  });

  it("DOES NOT allow deletion", async () => {
    if(!testEnv) return
    const storage = testEnv.authenticatedContext("user123").storage();
    await testEnv.withSecurityRulesDisabled(async (context) => {
      await uploadBytes(ref(context.storage(), "hi.jpg"), require("../assets/images/placeholder.png"))
    })
    expect(assertFails(deleteObject(ref(storage, "hi.jpg")))).resolves.toBeTruthy()
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    if(!testEnv) return
    testEnv.cleanup();
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked on the library version you are using? It might caused by outdated or incompatible version with your Firebase project.